# Can the iPhone play Quicktime VR files?

Tags: iphone, quicktime

Couldn't find anything anywhere. Does the iPhone support Quicktime VR files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone does not have any support for Quicktime VR files.

Comment: That's too bad...

Answer (score 0):

## [iPano](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/ipano/id437354990?mt=8)

on the App store

> NEW - QuicktimeVR object support! Spin an object around and see it from any side.
>
> Views any image or QuicktimeVR including QTVR objects!